# Control Ubuntu 14.04 machine from Win8 machine

Tags: networking, windows-8, sharing

I want to control my Ubuntu 14.04 PC from my Windows 8 PC.
Both computers are on Cisco EPC3928S and I do not have any problems connecting other windows computers.
I can not get Windows 8 to see Ubuntu, neither Ubuntu to see Windows 8.

Comment: Hi, currently hard to work out what your problem is, could you please provide more details about your problem, steps you have tried, error message, info about your network configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick respond to my question. Finally, I managed to make both computers to see each other and to remotely control linux from win8. I had to switch to ubuntu 12. Now the problem is that VNC is not starting automatically like it did in 14.04. Also I do not know how to instal jriver software. There are instructions on their site but it seems that I am just not a linux guy.

Comment: Hi, please ask a new question for each of your problems :)